# What Output field to choose in calculator build with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, calculator

I am making a calculator app. I want to ask which widget can I use to display numbers. If I use `Text` then I can't edit it with cursor and if I use `TextField` keyboard pops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an implementation of a EditableText that might work for you. Just drop in this code:

```
class NoKeyboardEditableText extends EditableText {

  NoKeyboardEditableText({
    @required TextEditingController controller,
    @required TextStyle style,
    @required Color cursorColor,
    bool autofocus = false,
    Color selectionColor
  }):super(
      controller: controller,
      focusNode: NoKeyboardEditableTextFocusNode(),
      style: style,
      cursorColor: cursorColor,
      autofocus: autofocus,
      selectionColor: selectionColor,
      backgroundCursorColor: Colors.black
  );

  @override
  EditableTextState createState() {
    return NoKeyboardEditableTextState();
  }

}

class NoKeyboardEditableTextState extends EditableTextState {
  @override
  void requestKeyboard() {
    super.requestKeyboard();
    //hide keyboard
    SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
  }
}

class NoKeyboardEditableTextFocusNode extends FocusNode {
  @override
  bool consumeKeyboardToken() {
    // prevents keyboard from showing on first focus
    return false;
  }
}
```

This will create a EditableText that does not open the keyboard, but you can still move the cursor as normal. To add text, I would use a combination of the text(), value(), selection() methods for the TextEditingController. First get the value in the field, then get the position of the cursor with selection(), input whatever text you want at the selection index, and finally set the text for the controller to the resulting string.

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 1):

So, you can try this one

`TextField(showCursor: true, readOnly: true);`